# Appropriate model of Critical Discourse Analysis

Tags: discourse-analysis

I am preparing my PhD thesis in Applied Linguistics. I have created a corpus of governmental administrative documents and I want to prove the existence of ideology behind some specific linguistic choices relating to all linguistic levels (morphology, phonetics, syntax etc).

For example, the extensive use of archaisms or fossil words could prove that the author is using an older form of the written language because he believes it represents a higher language variety that lends prestige to his document.

Which -in your opinion- is the best CDA methodological approach to prove it? Fairclough? Van Dijk? Wodak? Someone else maybe?

Comment: I agree with you but i will focus on fossilized terms and really rare/uncommon words that belong to an older form of the modern written language

Comment: I have already found many archaisms and fossilized terms. It remains to prove ideology behind discourse. I forgot to mention that my survey relates to the Greek language. Maybe in Engllish that is not the case..

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The aforementioned phenomenon occures in a variety of administrative documents from all the ministries, such as contracts, press releases, financial documents, govermental circulars, etc. I focus on fossilized terms (learned elements) that were used in Ancient Greek for example, but today have been replaced   by modern words. However, they tend to be used in some occasions were the author wants to grant prestige to himself and to his discourse

Comment: Why don't you provide some examples? I still do not grasp what  you mean.

Comment: Lets assume that the authors of administrative governmental documents use terms or structures of Victorian English because it is consedered a high variety and they are trying to encircle themselves and the document with prestige. Furthermore, they even resort to hypercorrection: they combine structures of older versions of English with terms of modern English (hyperpurism) You can see about covert prestige in Labov and Trudgill

Comment: Those are not examples. If you don't want to supply them, it's difficult to help you and so far you can see that no one has stepped up to the plate here. I wonder why that is?